# Android: How to read the content of the wpa_supplicant.conf file on the rooted device?

Tags: android, root, wpa-supplicant

i have the following function which should to return content of the wpa_supplicant.conf file.

I tried read file by this way:

```
public static String readTextFile() {
        aBuffer = "";
        try
        {
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec("chmod +x /data/misc/wifi/wpa_supplicant.conf");
            File path= Environment.getDataDirectory();
            File myFile = new File("/data/misc/wifi/wpa_supplicant.conf");
            FileInputStream fIn = new FileInputStream(myFile);
            BufferedReader myReader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(fIn));
            String aDataRow = "";
            aBuffer = "";
            while ((aDataRow = myReader.readLine()) != null) {
                aBuffer += aDataRow + "\n";
            }
            myReader.close();

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Logger.e("Cannot read the file");
            Logger.e(e.getMessage());
        }
        return aBuffer;
    }
```

And i added into manifest file too:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

But when i trying to read the content of the file placed in the:

```
/data/misc/wifi/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

I always get the following exception:

```
 /data/misc/wifi/wpa_supplicant.conf: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
```

Should i use instead of the inputStream Output stred of the shell command? 
Fxp:

```
tail /data/misc/wifi/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

How can i solve this issue please?

Many thanks for any advice.

Comment: Really Nobody knows?

Comment: did you solve this issue?

Answer (score -1):

Is there a reason you're trying to do it by writing an application?

You're doing su, but that command elevates the privileges in a shell- of which you're not instantiating.. You'd have to run the code AS root.  Read the file normally at that point.